Questions regarding the initialization of the Viewer
Background
We integrate with ACC.
Our user can select a file version from ACC, we get the urn of the version, use that to get the manifest and download the SQLite properties DB (see "Accessing design metadata without the Viewer").
We extract some data from the SQLite properties DB and use that later for interaction with the viewer.
ACC translates files to SVF2.
For SVF2, you should initialize the viewer with env=AutodeskProduction2 and api=streamingV2_EU, see "Getting Started > Initializing the Viewer for SVF and SVF2 Support".
The SQLite properties DB stores 'old' SVF dbIDs.
The viewer has functions to map between SVF and SVF2 dbIDs, see "Temporary workaround for mapping between SVF1 and SVF2 IDs".
But we found that when we initialize the viewer for the old SVF, using env=AutodeskProduction and api=derivativeV2_EU, it all just works and there is no mapping required, no need to call remapDbId or reverseMapDbId.
The ACC SVF2 data is shown.
New functionality like “Large model experience” is available and seems to work.
Questions

What is 'initialize' doing exactly? The documentation just mentions:


You enable SVF or SVF2 support by passing the env and api parameters
when initializing the Viewer. The value you use for env and api
specifies an SVF derivative or an SVF2 derivative.


It only seems to control if you use SVF or SVF2 dbIDs with the viewer. Does it have wider implications?
Does that also control if data is streamed?
Does it control if the SVF2 optimizations are being used?

Could you clarify and/or extend the documentation?

By the current design, ACC/BIM360 translates both SVF & SVF2 for the uploaded supported design files, and the viewer of ACC/BIM360 Docs will load SVF2 format by default.
Re "What is 'initialize' doing exactly?"
This why we can load SVF/SVF2 with viewer for the same model from ACC/BIM360 by changing the initialization options: ( {env: AutodeskProduction, api: derivativeV2/derivativeV2_EU} vs {env: AutodeskProduction2, api: streamingV2/streamingV2_EU} )
However, only specifying {env: AutodeskProduction2, api: streamingV2/streamingV2_EU} work for SVF2. This one will tell APS viewer to load SVF2 format instead.
Re "Does that also control if data is streamed?" & "Does it control if the SVF2 optimizations are being used?"
Yes, when loading SVF2 models, APS viewer & ACC/BIM360 viewer will load the model contents/geometries with WebSocket. Loading SVF models, viewers will use HTTP requests instead, so the loading performance is slow in this case compared to SVF2.
The dbIds in SVF2 will be completely different from SVF ones because the Model Derivative service will remap the dbIds, so we need remapDbId or reverseMapDbId for mapping dbIds between SVF and SVF2, also between the 3D views in SVF2 and 2D views, when viewing SVF2 models. (note. SVF2 is 3D views only)
